# Include folder information when uploading files to a web server

Tags: c#, web-services, file-upload

I'm uploading files over to a web server via a web service from my local directory. The problem I have is when I have files with the same name but from different directories. For example, I have two files:

`Debug\Controls.Resources.dll`

`Release\Controls.Resources.dll`

When the first file gets uploaded, I get a `file already exists` error when the second file is being uploaded.

What I want to do is include the folder information from which a file belongs to such that when it finds the file with the same name, it will create a folder.

How do I upload the files such that I can include the folder information when it gets to the server? I'm thinking of creating a data structure and upload that object instead of the file.

```
public class FileUpload
{
private string ContainingFolder {get;set}
private File UploadFile {get;set;}
}
```

PS: I've already tried zipping the files but for some reason I don't want to go that way.

Comment: are all the files saved in the same folder?

Comment: @JoachimGotzes Yes, all files are saved in a `temp` folder in the server.

Comment: I then would recommend to create the folder structure there, or you catch that case and add a prefix to the file.

Comment: @JoachimGotzes Creating the folder structure on my web server would make it static. It would break when another file and folder is created in the future. Also, I can't prefix or suffix the file name since I have to save the name to the database.